# Excel Slicer based on scrollbar

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a slicer containing values from 0.00-1.00, connected to a pivottable.
I would like to have a scrollbar to control these slicer values instead of having to select them individually.

I have looked into the timeline option, but that obviously only applies to dates, which I can't use.

The second option I have been trying is the ActiveX controll scrollbar. I thought I'd then use the scroll bar as a maxium value for the slicer, but I don't know if it's possible to connect the slicer to a cell?

Comment: you would need to do something like set the progress bar min to 0 and max to 100, then you'd say something like `slicer1.value=progressbar1.value/100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding the slicer content as an extra row in the Pivottable and then recording a macro where I filter the content to some arbitrary values.

I then adjusted the macro to reference the cell values linked to the scroll bar.